# Undefined symbol with JsonCPP library in Linux 64. What am I missing?

Tags: c++, json, linker, jsoncpp

I'm using JsonCPP as a parser for Json in C++, the problem is when I declare my var `Json::Value root;`, its compiles very well but when I use it the program crashes showing this msg: `undefined symbol: _ZN4Json5ValueD1Ev`.
What I missing?

I thought that is was a linker problem so I put my library `libjson_linux-gcc-4.1.2_libmt.so` in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`, and the .h to `/usr/include/json` so when I call for the library in my code I do `#include <json/json.h>`.

Everything is fine because I can compile it very well! but I recieve the same crashes.

Is there any path that I am missing to link?

Thank you all!

PD: I forget to say that I'm not compiling with g++, I'm compiling with a makefile

Comment: Could you show your compiler's input and output?

Comment: I compile with g++ trhought console, in fact im newbie with c++ an also in Linux so I have no idea how I can show you that :S

Answer (score 1):

In addition to including the header file, you need to link to the library as well.

At the linking stage, add the argument `-ljson_linux-gcc-4.1.2_libmt`

Comment: Can you build an example of it? I thought I was linking my json lib when I was putting it on my /usr/lib folder. That's new for me.

Comment: @Urien , no, you have to explicitly tell your application which library you have to link to. , you'd do e.g. `gcc -o myprogram myprogram.cpp -ljson_linux-gcc-4.1.2_libmt`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, putting the libjson_linux-gcc-4.1.2_libmt.so to the same dir of your program located when running it.